# How do i test my for-loops and arraylist with JUnit in java

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, junit

hey i'm newbie when it comes to testing with JUnit and i dont know how to test for-loops/ Loops. In my code you can see some of the for-loops i have to test. I mostly want to test the top5 list method and the printListOfResults. Please help a friend in need

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;
/**
 * Write a description of class Discipline here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class Discipline 
{
    private String disciplineName;
    private HashMap <EliteSwimmer, Result> eliteResults;  

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Discipline.
     * @param disciplineName The discipline name.
     */
    public Discipline(String disciplineName)
    {
        this.disciplineName = disciplineName;
        eliteResults = new HashMap<EliteSwimmer, Result> () ;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of disciplineName.
     * @return the value of disciplineName.
     */
    public String getDisciplineName ()
    {
        return disciplineName;
    }

    /**
     * Add the elite swimmer's best training result.
     * @param elite The elite member.
     * @param res The elite member's best training result.
     */
    public void addEliteResults(EliteSwimmer elite, Result res)
    {
        if (res.getType() == 0) {
            eliteResults.put(elite, res);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Not a training result");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Print a list with the elite swimmers' best training results. 
     */
    public void printListofResults()
    {
        Set set = eliteResults.entrySet();
        Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry mentry = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
            System.out.println("Elite Swimmer: "+ ((EliteSwimmer)mentry.getKey()).getName());
            System.out.println("Result: " + ((Result) mentry.getValue()).getTime());

        }

    }

    /**
     * Print a list with the top 5 elite swimmers, based on their training results.
     */
    public void Top5List()
    {
        Set<Entry<EliteSwimmer,Result>> set = eliteResults.entrySet();
        List<Entry<EliteSwimmer,Result>> list = new ArrayList<Entry<EliteSwimmer,Result>>(set);
        Collections.sort( list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<EliteSwimmer,Result>>()
            {
                @Override
                public int compare( Map.Entry<EliteSwimmer,Result> o1, Map.Entry<EliteSwimmer,Result> o2 )
                {          return Double.compare(o1.getValue().getTime(), o2.getValue().getTime() ); }
            });

        LinkedHashMap<EliteSwimmer,Result> sortedHashMap=new LinkedHashMap<EliteSwimmer,Result>();  
        for (Map.Entry<EliteSwimmer,Result> entry: list) {  
            sortedHashMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());  
        }  
        int counter = 0;
        for(Map.Entry<EliteSwimmer,Result> entry: list)
        {counter ++;
            System.out.println("Elite swimmer: " + entry.getKey().getName()+"        Result: " +entry.getValue().getTime());
            if (counter == 5)
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If i were going to test the `printListofResults` method, i'd refactor the `println` invocation into a `PrintString` class with single method `print` that takes the string to be printed as an argument. Then, in the test, i'd mock the `PrintString` class and use a spy to verify the method was invoked once for each element in the set.

Answer (score 0):

At a quick glance the easiest way to test this is to separate the concern of printing from the business behavior.  In other words, have a method that finds the top 5 swimmers, returning them as part of the method signature, and test that method returns the correct swimmers for a particular scenario.  The printing of them can be done separately - potentially by another class entirely.

Proponents of unit testing will argue that it can result in better factored code - mixed concerns are harder to test, whereas code with a single responsibility is easier to test and also easier to understand, maintain, and evolve in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It's great that you want to test your code, and it's the right way to go. However, with the current implementation, it's hard to do specific assertions, because you function **Top5List** does to many things. 
Split it up into smaller logical parts, and do tests on that. For example:

1. List sortSwimmers(List<> unsorted)
2. EliteSwimmer getBestSwimmer(List swimmers)
3. String formattedPrint(EliteSwimmer swimmer)
4. String formattedPrint(List swimmer)

Then do unit test separatly for each.

> Also a general advice, try to do tests and coding beside each other,
>   then, it's much harder to end up hard to test code like this.